# Using String.replaceAll() to remove character combination

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, replaceall, replace

I need to remove all redundant hyphens in a given string, e.g.: "Bla----Bla---Bla--Bla" to "Bla-Bla-Bla-Bla", using as little code as possible.

At the moment I've implemented this:

```
url = url.replace('----', '-');
url = url.replace('---', '-');
url = url.replace('--', '-');
```

to achieve this.

Is there a way to use the String.replaceAll method to achieve this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use replaceAll with a regular expression as follows:

```
url = url.replaceAll('-+','-');
```

This says "match one or more (+) hyphens (-)" and we replace it with the singular hyphen (-).

Comment: An alternative would be `'-{2,}`, which specifies that any number of hyphens >= 2 get matched by the regex. Using `'-+'` is shorter, using `{x,y}` allows you to be more specific (x or more when y is left blank, between x and y instances when x and y are given)

Comment: Cool! It worked as expected! Thank you!